# Homogeneous function in Complex plane and its Periodicities

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, dynamical-systems

Consider A function $f:\mathbf{C}^2\rightarrow \mathbf{C}$ defined as $$f_{\alpha, \beta}(z,w)=\frac{\alpha}{z}+\frac{\beta}{w}$$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ both are complex number.

It is easy to see that $f(\lambda z, \lambda w)=\lambda^{-1}f(z,w)$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbf{C}$. Hence it is a kind of Homogeneous function of degree $-1$.

Now consider a dynamical system $$Z_{n+1}=\frac{\alpha}{z_n}+\frac{\beta}{z_{n-1}}$$

What can say about periodicity of the sequences? Is the above fact about homogeneity useful anyway in deriving periodicities?

Comment: Simul-posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/180331/periodicities-of-a-complex-dynamical-system, with no notification to either site.

Comment: Sorry. I did not know that one needs to notify before posting into two communities. I am sorry once again. I think you have really referred the same on behalf of me. Mathematically I did not find anything wrong although. However I am more interested in having your answer.